# Expand $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ in Laurent's Series in $z_0=i$ , derivate nth.

Tags: sequences-and-series

As the title I tried to expand in a Laurent's Series the function $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$  as :

$\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n (z-i)^n $

where : $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{(z+i)(z-i)^{n+2}}= Res(f,i)=lim_{z \rightarrow i} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\frac{d^{n+1}}{dz^{n+1}}(\frac{(z-i)^{n+2}}{(z+i)(z-i)^{n+2}})=\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)!}{(n+1)!(z+i)^{n+1}}|_{z=i}=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}}$

whereby : $f(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=-1}^{+\infty} (-\frac{z-i}{2i})^n$

The result is correct ( I see in the book ) but 
I wonder , you can extend the formula $f^{(n)} (z_0)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(z+a)^n}|_{z=z_0} $ in $f^{(n+k)} (z_0)=\frac{(-1)^n (n+k)!}{(z+a)^{n+k}}|_{z=z_0}$ ? Furthermore , there is a formula to calculate the nth derivate ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{z^2+1}=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{z-i}-\frac1{z+i}\right)=\frac1{2i(z-i)}-\frac1{2i}\frac1{z-i+i}=$$

$$=\frac1{2i(z-i)}+\frac12\frac1{1+\frac{z-i}i}=\frac1{2i(z-i)}+\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(z-i)^n}{i^n}=$$

$$=\frac1{2i(z-i)}+\frac12-\frac{z-i}{2i}-\frac{(z-i)^2}2+\ldots$$

Comment: Yes,You're right , but I have to resolve that excercise with that method ...

Comment: I really don't undestand what you're asking at the end: both equalities you wrote, as far as I see, are identical, only the first uses $\;n\;$ and the second one $\;k\;$

Comment: I ask.. is possible to exend $f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(z+a)^n}|_{z=z_0}$ in $f^{(n+1)}(z_0)$,$f^{(n+2)}(z_0)$,...,$f^{(n+k)}(z_0)$  ?

Comment: @JohnSnowden Again, I'm not sure what you mean: the one you wrote **is the formula** for the coefficients of the Laurent series, for *any* $\;n\;$ .

Comment: $f^{(n)} (z_0)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(z+a)^n}|_{z=z_0} $  =>  $f^{(n+k)} (z_0)=\frac{(-1)^n (n+k)!}{(z+a)^{n+k}}|_{z=z_0}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\frac {1} {1+z^2} = \frac {1} {(z-i)(z+i)}$. Now $\frac {1} {z+i}=\frac {1}{1-\frac{z-i}{-2i}}$ thus by geometry expansion we get $\frac {1} {z+i}= \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} (\frac {z-i}{-2i})^n$, combining those two we get $\frac {1} {1+z^2} = \frac {1} {(z-i)} \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} (\frac {z-i}{-2i})^n=\sum_{n=-1} ^{\infty} (\frac {z-i}{-2i})^n $ and by uniqueness we get that this is the Laurent's Series. Notice that the sum is from $n=-1$ because there is a pole in $i$.

Comment: Yes,You're right , but I have to resolve that excercise with that method ...